# jdbc vs jpa implementation

Tags: jdbc, jpa-2.0

How do I do this in JPA??

DataBase:

```
School
------
id int PK
name varchar
state int FK (State(id))

State
-----
id int PK
desc varchar
```

Java:

```
SchoolShow
----------
int id;
String name;
int iState;
String sState;
```

Code:

```
select sc.name, st.desc from school sc, state st where st.id=sc.state and sc.id=?

while(rs.hasNext()){
    SchoolShow ss=new SchoolShow();
    ss.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    ss.setSState(rs.getString("desc"));
}
```

¿could I have an @Entity with properties from different tables?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create entities for the `School` and `State` tables and use a `@ManyToOne` relation on the `state` attribute of the `School` entity to reference the state.

Then you can query like this, navigating over the relation from school to the state:

```
List result = em.createQuery("SELECT sc.name, sc.state.desc FROM School sc").getResultList();
```

Note that each element of the list is an `Object[]`. You will need to iterate over them and assign the values to your DTO.

You can also use JPA constructor expressions for typesafety and less clutter:

```
List<DTO> dtos = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.DTO( sc.name, sc.state.desc) FROM School sc").getResultList();
```

The DTO type must have a constructor with all the relevant attributes.

Comment: thanks kostja! this was what i was thinking, but i wanted to assure i need an object attribute in school -> state, instead of a primitive. So JPA will be so much slower than JDBC...why people use it???

Comment: @leccionesonline - you're welcome :) JPA, as a JDBC abstraction, will indeed be slower than JDBC in most cases, but not all - JPA provides proper caching while JDBC does not. I have yet to see a real JPA-JDBC benchmark though, so I cant say how much slower. The reason I'm using JPA is that JDBC requires much more boilerplate code, which is a drain on dev time both while writing and reading.

Comment: the reason I'm moving to JPA is I've heard JDBC is not supported by Spring anymore, JPA has become reference implementation

Comment: @leccionesonline I think they are still retaining the JDBC functionality (http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jdbc-extensions), but Spring Data is definitely moving towards JPA, so your investment is not for naught :)